# Why is my truffle migration failed?

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs, truffle-migration

I executed the following:

```
➜  voting_truffle truffle migrate
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Voting.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/Users/glaksmono/Documents/Blockchain Projects/voting_truffle/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
  function Migrations() {
  ^
Spanning multiple lines.
,/Users/glaksmono/Documents/Blockchain Projects/voting_truffle/contracts/Migrations.sol:15:3: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
  function setCompleted(uint completed) restricted {
  ^
Spanning multiple lines.
,/Users/glaksmono/Documents/Blockchain Projects/voting_truffle/contracts/Migrations.sol:19:3: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
  function upgrade(address new_address) restricted {
  ^
Spanning multiple lines.

Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:43303:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:331156:36
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:175492:11
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:314196:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:315621:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70159:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70449:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70604:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70564:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
➜  voting_truffle
```

I have 2 migration files:
1. `migrations/1_initial_migration.js`
2. `migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js`

The content of `migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js` is the following:

```
var Voting = artifacts.require("./Voting.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Voting, ['Rama', 'Nick', 'Jose'], {gas: 6700000});
};
/* As you can see above, the deployer expects the first argument to   be the name of the contract followed by constructor arguments. In our case, there is only one argument which is an array of
candidates. The third argument is a hash where we specify the gas required to deploy our code. The gas amount varies depending on the size of your contract.
*/
```

Here's the status of my blockchain synchronization from `geth attach`:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 2179367,
  highestBlock: 2179534,
  knownStates: 5799770,
  pulledStates: 5764000,
  startingBlock: 0
}
>
```

I've been trying to figure this out for days, and I'm stuck. Any ideas?

I'm trying to follow [this](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f) tutorial, and I'm stuck in the migration section.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem - `Error: authentication needed: password or unlock`

You need to open up the geth console and type `personal.unlockAccount("address", "password", 0)` to deploy the contracts to ropsten.

He says it in the tutorial in section 4 here:

```
mahesh@projectblockchain:~/voting$ truffle console
truffle(default)> web3.personal.newAccount('verystrongpassword')
'0x95a94979d86d9c32d1d2ab5ace2dcc8d1b446fa1'
truffle(default)> web3.eth.getBalance('0x95a94979d86d9c32d1d2ab5ace2dcc8d1b446fa1')
{ [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
truffle(default)> web3.personal.unlockAccount('0x95a94979d86d9c32d1d2ab5ace2dcc8d1b446fa1', 'verystrongpassword', 15000)
// Replace 'verystrongpassword' with a good strong password.
// The account is locked by default, make sure to unlock it before using the account for deploying and interacting with the blockchain.
```

He has 1500, I put 0 in as the third variable. That indicates the amount of time you want the account unlocked. If you put 0 it unlocks for the entire session.

Comment: Do you actually execute the migration within the `truffle console`? Doesn't seem working with me: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/a260ca02cd741ad5d1e9f107c663e4cc

Comment: Instead of using the truffle console try using the standard geth console. When you first start geth on ropsten you should get an IPC endpoint. It should look like `INFO [08-06|08:06:14] IPC endpoint opened: <path>`. 

Once you get that path, type `geth attach ipc:<path>`. That should open up the console. In that console type `personal.unlockAccount('0x60a9e63750adfafc77bd0ba692a20e4dbe330c24', 'pass', 0`.

Comment: Then where do you type the `truffle migration`? I don't think you can type that in the `geth console`.

Comment: `truffle migrate --network ropsten` in the project folder like you would normally. You should have 3 tabs open. One running geth, one running geth console, and one to migrate the contracts

Comment: This is my `truffle.js`: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/f97543cf6da57fa4234f3445df977836 and I'm getting this error now: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/e7dbbff3a31faae27f0eaefe587ac0e4

Comment: Do you have enough ETH in your account to deploy the contracts?

Comment: I have 2 ether, isn't that enough? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x60a9e63750adfafc77bd0ba692a20e4dbe330c24

Comment: I just re-execute this again after I have my block fully synced, and I'm getting the following error: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/c25444e25afeffedcdb85047ea482638 here are my `truffle.js`: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/40434ca612d9c9237676e82c561d0971 ideas? I also can see something changed in my account: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x60a9e63750adfafc77bd0ba692a20e4dbe330c24

Comment: Can you paste the contract in a gist as well?

Comment: Here's the contract: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/ccbd947036616d6c82c6722e3cc7fee6

Comment: I'm just seeing the migrations file. What about the contract?

Comment: Sorry, got it. Here you go: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/16c9e5bc4c8d3931168164b33a9afa38

Comment: Try getting the gas limit for your truffle framework like this 

```$ truffle console
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getBlock("pending").gasLimit```

Change the gas amount in your truffle.js file to what you get.

Comment: Did that, then I re-execute the migration, but I'm still getting this: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/5e4d91640d62a1b56d847324dd6976b6

Comment: Does it work in testrpc?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry, I'm quite noob on these things :(

Comment: Instead of running ropsten, close it and type `testrpc` or `ganache-cli` depending on which one you have installed. If you don't have either download `ganache-cli`

Comment: It works on `testrpc` - not really sure it doesn't work on `ropsten`

Comment: Man. It seems like it's just a gas issue at this point. I see you're putting in 6,700,000 gas.. Maybe bring it down a bit? It has to be some sort of config that's not right.

Comment: I even tried changing it to 500,000 and I'm still getting issues. Feels like there's something wrong with Ropsten network, is there any other network I can use for testing purposes? https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/df7cbf06c2cb97142c972f22c00ef183